# Nested enumerate and inlineitem leads to inconsistent label spacing

Tags: enumerate, enumitem, inline

I've typed an exam up, and my nested enumerates seem to cause a problem with the separation between my label and the actual line item.  This happens specifically when using the **inlineitem** command, which allows me to list more than one item on the same line.  The first item in the line has more spacing between the label and the item than subsequent items on the same line...

Here is my minimum working example:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, graphicx, fancyhdr, color,booktabs, calc,caption,pgfplots, enumitem}
\makeatletter

\newcommand{\inlineitem}[1][]{
\ifnum\enit@type=\tw@
    {\descriptionlabel{#1}}
  \hspace{\labelsep}
\else
  \ifnum\enit@type=\z@
       \refstepcounter{\@listctr}\fi
    \quad\@itemlabel\hspace{\labelsep}
\fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=.75cm,align=left,labelsep=0cm,label=\textbf{Problem \arabic*. }]

\item Prove each of the following:

\begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=.75cm,labelsep=0cm,align=left,label=(\alph*)]

\item $x = y$ {\color{white}......} \inlineitem $x = 2y$ {\color{white}......} \inlineitem $3x - 5 = 2020$

\end{enumerate}

\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I propose to use the `tasks` environment, or   `shortenumerate` from `shortlst`.

Example with `tasks`:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, graphicx, fancyhdr, color,booktabs, calc,caption,pgfplots, enumitem}
\usepackage{tasks}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=.75cm,align=left,labelsep=0cm,label=\textbf{Problem \arabic*. }]

  \item Prove each of the following:

        \begin{tasks}[counter-format =(tsk[a]), label-offset=1.25em](3)
          \task $x = y$ {\color{white}......} \task $x = 2y$ {\color{white}......} \task $3x - 5 = 2020$
          \task $y = z$ {\color{white}......} \task $y = 6z$ {\color{white}......} \task $z-10 = 1010$
        \end{tasks}

\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice!  What else can go inside of tsk[] instead of a?  How would I do roman numerals?  Or little roman numerals?

Comment: Also, what if you want to make two rows of items?

Comment: Just use `\tsk[r]`. This is explained in § 4 of the documentation.

Comment: All this is automatic. Please take a look at my updated answer.

Comment: So it looks like the number you specify at the end of your "begin" line will be the number of tasks on one line.  So if you write the number 3 but type in 4 tasks, you will have 2 lines, the first line having 3 tasks and the second line having 1 task.  Is that right?

Comment: It's exactly that. The advantage of `shortlst` is that, in case an item sets over more than one column, the package uses the required number of columns automatically, while with tasks you have to specify how many columns you need.

Comment: Thank you very much for introducing me to this nice package!